# Joining multiple table order

Tags: join, relational-database

I think I have read somewhere that join in associative and commutative so order of table in join query is irrelevant, is this true?!!

If so then I have a situation here where I have 4 tables like this:
`S(s_id, sname, status, city)` supplier
`J(j_id, jname, city)` job/project
`P(p_id, pname, color, weight, city)` part 
`SPJ(s_id, p_id, j_id, qnty)` supplier - parts - jobs

So my question is are the following joins the same?
`S join J join SPJ`
`S join SPJ join J`

Comment: in result it is probably return the same resut, Open the execution plan(ms sql) to see the different(cost, execution time, etc)

Comment: am not talking about mysql or any database I am just talking about the definition of join so if I join `S` and `J` first they will be joined according to `city` then joining this result with `SPJ`  will join according to `s_id` and `p_id`. On other hand If I take `S` and `SPJ` first this will join on `s_id` then if I take this result and joined with `P` would join on `city` and `p_id` which is clearly not the same, either I am doing this wrong or multiple joins aren't necessarily associative.

Comment: I do not talk about mysql or any database. I tell you that S JOIN J JOIN SPJ and S JOIN SPJ JOIN j can return the same Data Result. If you want to see the difference seek information in the Execution Plan (if you are using MS SQL). it will shows u the difference in Execution Time, Number of rows, and resource cost.

Comment: @Doggynub If by *join* you mean a *Natural Join* in the relational algebra then the answer is yes. Natural Join is associative and commutative. For SQL-style joins that isn't necessarily the case.